# Is there a possibility to submit a hubspot form from js?

Tags: javascript, hubspot

I embedded a hubspot form in my HTML website, but I want it to be hidden as it doesn't really meet the website design. What I want is to submit that form, by clicking a regular html button. How could I do that?

Comment: If the form is a standard HTML form then you could just set your forms action to the action of the hubspot form. This only works if there is no CSRF protection. If hubspot supports CORS it might be possible with CORS

Comment: _"as it doesn't really meet the website design"_ Could you style it with some custom CSS so it does meet the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed possible. Hubspot has a rich documentation you can make use of. I think what you are looking for is [submit data for a form](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form).

Their form-API is REST based, meaning you communicate through sesionless HTTP requests with them. This means that you just have to call their endpoint (e.g. by using `fetch()`) whenever you want to submit your form.

Since you mentioned that you don't like the form design, there is a field in their API that allows to append **CSS classes** to the form elements. You may want to try customizing your form with custom CSS first. (https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/advanced_form_options)